# How to filter the client data in sync framework?

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I setup some filters on remote provider so that I don't download everything. Now I would like to setup some filters on the client end, so I don't upload everything.

I am using the local database cache objects in c#

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, there is no out-of-the-box support for adding a filter to the SqlCeClientSyncProvider.

if you want, you can try intercepting the dataset in the ChangesSelected event and filter out rows you dont want to sync to the server.

have a look at a similar approach here: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/

Comment: You might also want to consider utilising ReactiveExtensions for this filtering: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609
Not quite sure how you'd achieve that in this setting, but it certainly makes your intention very clear if you can hook it in.